# Scrolling down leads to activate the pull down refresh option

Tags: android, listview, android-scrollview

i have attached the Swipe Refresh Layout as a top parent node to offer pull down refresh option to user.

So when i scroll down, i cant able to scroll, automatically the pull down option starts loading.

i have searched some stack overflow question regarding the same issue. they are saying listen the scrolling and disable the pull down option based on the list view current index.

i have tried to listen it. but i cant able listen any event when scrolling down.

my list view object:

```
    mListView = (ListView) getView().findViewById(android.R.id.list);
```

can anyone please help me. any other interesting solution or work around.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I did it this way and it's working perfectly:

```
class YourActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ViewTreeObserver.OnScrollChangedListener { 
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mListView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnScrollChangedListener(this);
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
      mListView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnScrollChangedListener(this);
}


@Override
public void onScrollChanged() {
    if (mListView.getFirstVisiblePosition() == 0) {
        swipeRefresh.setEnabled(true);
    } else {
        swipeRefresh.setEnabled(false);
    }
}
}
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Mohanand. Awesome... but instead getScrollY() i have used getFirstVisiblePosition(). its working perfectly. you have saved my time. thanks...

Comment: True that  getFirstVisiblePosition() would work. Welcome :)

Comment: HI Mohanad. i have one more query. consider there is no listview in a layout, when the first element of the layout is visible then i have to enable/disable the swipe refresh layout. how it can be implemented?

Comment: you can add the addOnScrollChangedListener to the scrolling view (list view, scrollview, webview...etc).

Answer (score 2):

In my case I solved the problem by changing the **Scrollview** by a **NestedScrollView**.

After switching to a NestedScrollView it worked correctly